# Ponteiro para vetor com alocação dinâmica em C

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Consegui fazer este exercício dentro da `main`, contudo o mesmo conceito não tem dado certo ao utilizar funções.

O objetivo do programa é simples, ler seis valores e exibi-los.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int *i;
    int *valor[6];
    int temp = 0;

    i = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    valor[6] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (*i=0; *i<6; *i = *i + 1){
        scanf("%d", (valor+*i));
    }

    for (*i=0; *i<6; *i = *i + 1){
        printf("%d\n", *(valor+*i));
    }
}
```

Como está o código que tenta cumprir o mesmo objetivo usando funções:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void write(int *i, int *valor){
    for (*i=0; *i<6; *i = *i+1){
        scanf("%d", &valor[*i]);
    }
}

void read(int *i, int *valor){
    for (*i=0; *i<6; *i = *i+1){
        printf("%d\n", valor[*i]);
    }

}

int main(){
    int *i = 0;
    int *valor;

    i = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    valor = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*6);

    write(&i, &valor);
    read(&i, &valor);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso daqui vai criar um array com 6 ponteiros de inteiros.

```
int *valor[6];
```

As posições desse array são numeradas de 0 a 5. Porém aqui, você atribui algo à posição 6, fora do array:

```
valor[6] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Isso daí é uma violação do tamanho do array. Deve funcionar por sorte apenas porque a área de memória invadida além do array não deve estar sendo utilizada para mais nada.

Aqui, ocorre algo estranho:

```
scanf("%d", (valor+*i));
```

Usar `(valor+*i)` é o mesmo que `&valor[*i]`. Apesar de equivalente, recomendo fortemente a segunda forma por ser muito mais legível e compreensível. Da mesma forma, `*(valor+*i)` é equivalente a `valor[*i]`.

O erro está nessas duas linhas:

```
write(&i, &valor);
read(&i, &valor);
```

O que você queria era isso:

```
write(i, valor);
read(i, valor);
```

O motivo é que o `&` é normalmente usado para dar o endereço de memória de uma variável, criando então um ponteiro. Ocorre que `i` e `valor` já são ponteiros, e você quer passar o endereço de memória para o qual apontam. Ao usar um `&` em cada, você estaria passando o endereço de memória do ponteiro, criando um ponteiro-para-ponteiro, o que não é o que você quer.